# Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have some json structured so

```
({
"items" : [
{
  "color" : "B83D7A",
  "name" : "example"
}
]})
```

and the rest of the code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("favourites.json", function (data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        var url = "http://" + item.name + ".com";
        var color = item.color;
        htmlString += '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">';
        htmlString += '<p style="color: #' + color + ';">';
        htmlString += item.name;
        htmlString += '</p></a>';
    });
    $('#favourites').html(htmlString);
});
</script>
<div id="favourites"></div>
```

I'm not getting any errors but nothing is happening,
please help as I have no idea what is wrong.
Thank you :)

Comment: Is that trailing comma in the actual code, or was it just a typo?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug or similar to set a breakpoint on your JS block and seeing what values you get back and where it might be failing?

Comment: Also, what happens if you just change it to this: `$.getJSON('favourites.json', function (data) { alert(data); });`

Comment: Is your "favourites.json" in the same place as the html page with the code above?

Comment: can't get it on firefox 4.0 yet but on chrome inspect I don't get anything

Comment: it solved the question because it worked. I don't see what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 4):

Your json is invalid, you have a trailing comma, and you are using `(` and `)` when it should be `[` and `]`.

try this:

```
[{
"items" : [
{
  "color" : "B83D7A",
  "name" : "example"
}
]}]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you change your JSON to be wrapped in an Array, you'll need to access `items` from the first member of the Array. `data[0].items` instead of `data.items`

Comment: still not working, and without any console errors. I might give up and try appending the data

Answer (score -3):

Try changing version to jQuery 1.3. Its not working for jQuery 1.4 for some reason.

Edit1: As pointed out in comments by @Dave its a json syntax issue
extra comma and braces around are not correct.
use following json and it will work fine.

```
{
"items" : [
{
  "color" : "B83D7A",
  "name" : "example"
}
]}
```

Comment: The reason it wasn't working in jQuery 1.4 is that 1.4 uses `JSON.parse()` when available (which is faster and more secure), and `JSON.parse()` will not successfully parse invalid JSON.  If at all possible, fix the JSON instead of reverting to a two-year-old version of jQuery.  Avoiding 1.4 or 1.5, you're missing out on a lot of bugfixes and performance improvements.  At this point, you'll even find plugins that won't work with 1.3.

Comment: Version 1.3 & 1.4 of what? If you mean jQuery, the newest version is 1.5.

Comment: This is like trying to submit an English class paper written in French and demanding a new teacher when you get an F.  The OP's input is not `JSON`, switching to a broken parser masks the problem, it doesn't fix it.